# Excel VBA: Inserting value in cell using xlDown and Offset

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having some trouble getting my code to insert a value from an InputBox. The offending lines in particular are the following:

```
Set p = nPoints.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            p.Value = nPointVal
```

What this *should* do is find the last row of a spreadsheet, the first available cell to the right, and insert the stored value `nPointVal`. However, instead of doing so, it simply doesn't insert anything. Any help is greatly appreciated, and my full code is below.

```
Sub takeTwo()

On Error Resume Next

Dim fNameString As Variant
Dim lNameString As Variant
Dim sEmailString As Variant
Dim nPointVal As Integer
Dim sEventName As String
Dim n As Integer, r As Long, c As Range, d As Range, e As Range, p As Range, sE As Range
Dim fName As Range, lName As Range, sEmail As Range, nPoints As Range
Dim lEvent As Integer
Set fName = ActiveSheet.Range("FirstName")
Set lName = ActiveSheet.Range("LastName")
Set sEmail = ActiveSheet.Range("eMailAddr")


fNameString = Split(Application.InputBox("First Names in comma delimited format.", Type:=2), ",")
lNameString = Split(Application.InputBox("Last Names in comma delimited format.", Type:=2), ",")
sEmailString = Split(Application.InputBox("Email Addresses in comma delimited format.", Type:=2), ",")
nPointVal = InputBox("Please enter a point value for this event")
sEventName = InputBox("Please enter the name of the event.")

lEvent = NextEmptyColumn(Range("A1"))
Set sE = Range("A1").Offset(0, lEvent)
sE.Value = sEventName
' sEventPos = sE.Offset(0, lEvent)

If fNameString <> False And lNameString <> False Then

    For i = LBound(fNameString) To UBound(fNameString)

        fNameString(i) = Trim(fNameString(i)) ' Trim off leading and trailing whitespace.
        lNameString(i) = Trim(lNameString(i)) ' Trim off leading and trailing whitespace.

        Set c = fName.Find(fNameString(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set d = lName.Find(lNameString(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If c And d Is Nothing Then

            Set c = fName.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            c.Value = fNameString(i)
            Set d = lName.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            d.Value = lNameString(i)
            Set e = sEmail.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            e.Value = sEmailString(i)
            Set p = nPoints.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            p.Value = nPointVal

            Dim s As Range ' Our summation range
            Set s = Range(c.Offset(0, 5), c.Offset(0, c.EntireRow.Columns.Count - 1))

            ' c.Offset(1, 3).Formula = "=((" & s.Address & ""

        End If

    Next


End If
```

End Sub

Comment: You don't ever set the range `nPoints` to anything. If you are trying to find the last cell in a column, it is better practice to go from the last row in the sheet and go up.

Comment: besides I feel like you want `If c Is Nothing And d Is Nothing Then` Instead of `If c And d Is Nothing Then`

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is almost always a very bad idea. It often functions as `On Error Mislead Programmer`. Delete it so that you can see where the bugs are.

Comment: To temper my comment: `On Error Resume Next` in the middle of the code, followed immediately by something like trying to open a file for reading, followed immediately by a conditional like `If Err.Number > 0 Then ...` followed immediately by `On Error GoTo 0`, is a common enough error-handling idiom and is unproblematic. Your use isn't like that -- it is global and has the effect of hiding all run-time errors, making code needlessly hard to debug. Don't globally suppress errors -- eliminate them if possible, handle them if not.

Comment: @Kyle: What range would I set `nPoints` to if the range is yet to be created by this same code?

Comment: Kyle is right, first you need to set the search range, e.g. a particular column, before you attempt to find the last empty row in it. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/918/methods-for-finding-the-last-used-row-or-column-in-a-worksheet#t=201609241616218880058

Answer (score 0):

So I found a simpler solution:

```
Set p = fName.End(xlDown).Offset(0, lEvent)
            p.Value = nPointVal
```

This references the same row in which the inserted name is on, which is what we want because the point value is related to this person. Someone please give advice if there could be some issues with this.